# how to send signal to (parent process?) telling the parent that the child is crashing

Tags: bash, shell, docker, signals, container

This is probably not a best practice, but I am trying it out.
I have this entrypoint.sh file that I use with docker like so:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

here was entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

args="$@"
echo "docker container arguments: '$args'"


"${args}" || {
    echo "Application exited with a non-zero code: '$?'";
    exit 1;
 }
```

well, in fact I updated it to be like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

args="$@"
echo "docker container arguments: '$args'"

while true; do
  "${args}" || {
    echo "Application exited with a non-zero code: '$?'";
    kill -SIGUSR1 "$(ps -o ppid= -p $$)"  ##### THIS
    sleep 3;
  };
done;
```

doing the forever loop is probably a bad idea - we should just let it crash and restart a new container.

But for the sake of argument - *my question is* -> is there some signal that I can send to the container orchestrator that my process keeps crashing, so to take it out and put in a new one?

if there is no new code to be deployed, then I would just let it restart itself after a 3 second interval. If there is new code, then certainly deploy a new container.

Comment: In any case,that `args="$@"` makes no sense. Should be `args=( "$@" )` and use `"${args[@]}"` thereafter or drop that intermediary variable altogether and call `"$@"` directly (and then you can use sh instead of bash and avoid having to add bash to your containers). Also note that standard sh and bash have `$PPID` for the id of the parent of the process that executed the shell (at shell startup time)

Comment: Those are meant to be containers, so if processes in there could send signals to processes outside the container, that would be a flaw in the design.

Comment: right, but when it exits, who collects that exit signal? or maybe that's not a signal? but at least it can listen for exits? So question is how to send a signal that it is crashing without actually exiting, if that makes sense

Comment: There is not "exit signal", there's "exit code". The parent automatically receives a signal notifying it that the child completed, and then it could check the exit code of the completed child. In the case of `docker`, when the container terminates, `docker` collects the exit status. See [How to get the numeric exit status of an exited docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46300610/how-to-get-the-numeric-exit-status-of-an-exited-docker-container).